# Odoo automated server action to trigger another server action

Tags: odoo

Let's say I set up Server Action A on the `stock.inventory` model. This action simply logs a value and then calls Sever Action B (which has a database ID of 366). The python code in the action is just:

```
log('running server action a')
value = {
  "type": "ir.actions.server",
   "id": 366,
}
```

Then, in Server Action B, which is on the `product.product` model, the python code is just:

```
log('running server aciton b')
```

Now, when I add Server Action A to the "More" menu, and manually trigger it from the browser on a `stock.inventory` object, both actions successfully run. In other words, I see both 'running server action a' and 'running server action b' in the logs.

Now, I create an Automated Action to trigger Server Action A on Update or Create of a `stock.inventory` object. After doing this, and updating or creating a `stock.inventory` object via the UI, I only see 'running server action a' in the logs. In other words, Server Action B never gets triggered like it did when I ran the same experiment manually from the "More" menu.

So, my question is whether or not it is possible to trigger a second server action from the first server action if the first server action is triggered by an automated action.

Comment: How are you calling the action? I think from the context of an automated action you need to call the method not return an action. The semantics for these kinds of issues can seem bizarre. I was calling a server action which returned a window action and nothing was working until I assigned the action value the returned window action. However under normal circumstances I would have simply returned the window action and expected it to load the view.

Comment: I am not sure but I wonder if actions returned from functions are treated differently when called from a browser than from code. It is possible you may have to call the other method directly instead of returning an action which really just calls the method anyways.

Comment: @PhillipStack I think you're right. It seems like when you "return an action", that is something the browser understands. It knows to call the server and execute the returned action. I would love to simply call the method like you suggest, but unfortunately I am doing all of this on a version of Odoo Online, meaning, I don't have access to the source code. I am adding these actions through the UI, and can't figure out a way to trigger an action from another server-side.

Comment: What version are you using? I think you can define code if you have access to the admin --> settings --> actions section.

Comment: Version 10. I haven't seen that menu. The only one I have seen is the one where I am defining the server actions which is settings / technical / actions / server actions

Comment: Are you logging in as admin? I am not sure if you need developer mode activated or not. But when I bring up a server action it shows me the python code box. The pics are from v8 but I just brought up a v10 and it looks the exact same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this working and the solution is very simple. This seems like a pretty cool way for Odoo Online users to treat server actions as functions that can return values to the calling server action.

Here's an example.

**Server Action A**

```
a = env['ir.actions.server'].browse(409)
ctx = dict(env.context or {})
ctx.update({'active_id': 169, 'active_model': 'purchase.order'})
a.with_context(ctx).run()
```

**Server Action B (ID = 409)**

```
raise Warning(record)
```

When you trigger the first action, you'll get the string `purchase.order(169,)` as output.

Even cooler, if the second server assigns a value to `action`, it is returned to the first action. For example:

**Server Action A**

```
a = env['ir.actions.server'].browse(409)
ctx = dict(env.context or {})
ctx.update({'active_id': 169, 'active_model': 'purchase.order'})
resp = a.with_context(ctx).run()
raise Warning(resp)
```

**Server Action B (ID = 409)**

```
action = record.id
```

When you trigger the first server action, you'll see 169 as the response.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the admin section. You should be able to call the function directly. In odoo8 it looks like this.

[image]

Pick your server action

[image]

Notice the python code section. You should be able to locate the model you need and execute the function directly.

```
action = self.env['addon.model'].the_fun()
```

To execute another action, try the following.

```
action = self.env['ir.actions.server'].ref('xml_id_of_action')
action.run_action_code_multi()
```

Here is the description

`run_action_code_multi(self, *args, **kwargs)
Override to allow returning response the same way action is already
returned by the basic server action behavior. Note that response has
priority over action, avoid using both.`

Comment: Yes I am aware of the python code field, that is how I created the actions in the first place and included code to log values as shown in the original question. The issue that I want to trigger another action from within that code box and I don't know how to do it. Does that make sense?

Comment: Well I am not entirely sure what context you are confined to with regards to calling odoo function within the python code box. I will update my answer. Try to simply call the function on your other action. I do not know how to call the action. But you can probably call the function.

Comment: I can't simply call the method directly because the method doesn't exist since I am using odoo online. There is no method, it's another server action. Unless a server action is somehow automatically given a name allowing it to be called as a method on the model? That would be nice, but sounds like it's not true.

Comment: Alright. Well your other server action, why not just execute the code which it is supposed to execute? If you have an action with code that calls another action which presumably executes some code. Why not cut out the middle man. Just execute the the second actions code.

Comment: The second action contains logic to set a field on the product.product model that I would like isolate. Meaning, I want to be able to trigger that code from different places. Like when a stock.move is created and when a sale.order is created. Things like that.

Comment: Alright, I just did some digging. I think I have the code you want. I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks, that's getting me closer I think. However, the method signature I see in V10 is `def run_action_code_multi(self, action, eval_context=None):`. I also don't have an XML ID because I'm using the UI. Therefore, I can retrieve the action with `action = env['ir.actions.server'].browse(368)`, but how do I call the `run_action_code_multi` method? It requires an `action` argument. What would that be in this case?

Comment: I also noticed that the `ir.action.server` has a `run()` method. I tried simply doing `action.run()` but I get an error: `AttributeError: 'ir.actions.server' object has no attribute 'setdefault'`

Comment: Seems like I was finally able to get this working using the `run` method. Answer posted in case you're curious.

Comment: Great news! So what was causing the setdefault error you mentioned previously? Or was it just something silly?

Comment: I'm guessing it had something to do with the fact that I wasn't calling `with_context` before `run`. Meaning, the action was trying to run without a context or something like that.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for updating your post.